# Neo4j database is not visible after loading with neo4j-admin import

Tags: neo4j

I imported my csv using the neo4j-admin import tool using this commend line (on windows)

```
bin\neo4j-admin.bat import --database badges3 --id-type STRING --ignore-empty-strings true --nodes import\BBnode.csv
```

the process completes and shows a success message

```
IMPORT DONE in 2s 341ms.
Imported:
  178 nodes
  0 relationships
  534 properties
Peak memory usage: 1.004GiB
```

however, when I go to the neo4j browser, I dont see the database there

is there a missing step to mount the database?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to run this in the system database

`:use system`
`create database badges3`

See https://neo4j.com/developer/manage-multiple-databases/

Comment: Thanks that worked: ran the command to create database and then restarted the database .

Comment: In neo4j-admin documentation there is no explanation that neo4j server must be stopped during import.